# Javascript One onclick Return Twice Result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

This is my code

```
<div class="rating">
  @for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    @if ($i <= ceil($rating[0]->average))
      <i id="{{$i}}" style="cursor:pointer" class="fa fa-star rating"></i>
    @else 
      <i id="{{$i}}" style="cursor:pointer" class="fa fa-star-o rating"></i>
    @endif
  @endfor
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.rating').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{url('rating')}}",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id_artikel: "{{$artikel->artikel_id}}",  _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', value:id},
        success: function(response){
          alert('Bintang berhasil anda berikan!'); 
      },
      error: function(){
          alert('Bintang gagal anda berikan!')
      }
  });
});

</script>
```

When i click i got twice result. The first give the correct 'id' and others give null. I was try to use unbind, but still give me twice result. I also try to make just only one  and still give me twice result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have two elements in the same DOM tree with a class `rating`.

I suggest renaming the class of your upmost `<div>` element to something else.

Comment: omg. how silly i am. I think i need to take a rest. Thank you! Answer accepted.